# vba code to save downloaded file using SaveAs dialog box

Tags: excel, vba

How can I download a file, then save it to wherever I want? The download part is done but when vba codes makes a click on download button a popup of SaveAs Dialog button gets opened.How to use that SaveAs Dialog box so that my macro continously runs without any pause in between.

Comment: Paste sample code. Not sure how SaveAs Dialog is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Iowak's comment that it's not clear what you're doing as how but as a bit of a shot in the dark, are you saying that you want to incorporate the Save As dialog into the VBA code that does the download rather than doing the save as as a separate action?

If so it's likely that all you need to do is incorporate the Application.GetSaveAsFilename method into your download code:

```
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _ 
 fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt") 
If fileSaveName <> False Then 
    MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName 
End If
```

If that's not it then as Iowak said you'd really need to post the code.